# onedrive music Meta data

Tags: meta, onedrive

I  make application with Live Connect REST API.

When I uploaded  Korean music files, I saw some problem.

The metadata of some Korean music files were well encoding, but some metadata were broken.

I did next process.

1. I uploaded a music file which's metadata encoded with "UTF-8"
2. I requested that file's information.that was broken.
3. I uploaded a music file which's metadata encoded with "UTF-16"
4. I requested that file's information.that was OK.

what encoding type is possible in SkyDrive server?and How can I get proper metadata?

Comment: Can you show an example of metadata you are receiving that is "broken" and what you are expecting?

Comment: Do you see the right information for these files in Windows when looking at the file's properties?

Comment: Dear Jeanine M S : I can see "³Ê¿¡°Ô" in my OneDrive as broken title. The correct name  is "너에게" as Korean letter.                       Dear RGregg : When I select file properties, I can't see any title,album,singer's name.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is over a year old, I think I have an answer.  It appears that OneDrive/SkyDrive only support ID3v2.3 ISO-8859-1 format, and not UTF8 or UTF16.  I just experienced this with adding some tracks I updated ID3 tags, and some tracks would show the proper Album Artist and the ones I updated did not.  I'm using MP3Tag to edit the tracks, which defaults to ID2v2.3 UTF16.  When I changed it to ISO-8859-1 format, OneDrive reads the ID